# Change style of a particular print page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'd like to style a lengthy HTML document I intend to print (/ convert to a PDF) so that, on a particular physical page, the body is styled in one way, while on every other page, it is styled another way. Specifically, I want the page which contains a particular paragraph (say `<p id="dramatic-scene">`) to have  a different background image from the other pages.

(The document itself is *not* structured for particular pages - instead of having a div for each page, we have a single container for the full content of the piece. If it were, we could probably just make the div for the page cover the entire dimensions of the page and give it the image - but I'm hoping to avoid having a rigid structure for the pages.)

In Selectors Level 4, there's a `:has()` pseudo-class (although part of a working draft, so it's [not supported anywhere yet](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has)). Is there anything similar which could specify a page to apply CSS to? Something like `@media print and (page-has: #dramatic-scene) {}`. I doubt there is - some quick searching didn't find anything - but I figure it's worth asking here.

More realistically, is there any  way I could simulate that with JavaScript? That'd be a fine solution for my use case. I couldn't find any info about that in searching though - any JS discussion related to printing seems to be about making buttons to print, swapping screen for print stylesheet before printing, etc, not making the page style react to the visible content.

Comment: For clarification, is this a single webpage with a single div container, that prints to multiple physical pages (of which you want a different background image on some). Or is it multiple web pages that each print to a single physical page?

Comment: It's the latter - a single webpage that will print to multiple physical pages. I've made an edit that hopefully clarifies!

Comment: A simple way around could be => `button.onclick = function () { }` check the I'd of the current page, then check if any of it's children has your id of interest. If yes, use JavaScript to change the `backgroundImage` of the page before calling `window.print()`

Comment: @officialpsoul The "current page" does not have an ID: there is a single container with the content for the entire document, which automatically gets split across pages by the web browser's page-printing code.